# What does $p_j(x)$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I am reading paper The Approximation Power Of Moving Least-squares by David Levin (and few more with same topic), and I have become a bit confused about notations.

What confuses me the most is $p_j(x)$ where $p$ is a polynomial (of degree $M$), $x$ is a vector (of size $D$) and $j$ is from $1$ to $J = \binom{D+M}{M}$. What is result of such thing, a vector, a polynomial, or a number? How to compute it?

The question is probably noobish, but we may be using different notation in my country, or I am just stupid. Either way, thank you for your patience and any replies.

Comment: It looks like $\binom{M+D}{M}$ is the number of monomials of degree less than or equal to $D$ in $M$ variables. So $J$ would then be an enumeration of them. _EDIT:_ I misunderstood what your question was asking. That symbol is the binomial symbol, and you can find information (now that you know its name) on Wikipedia.

Comment: The binomial symbol is used in $\LaTeX$ by writing \binom{n}{k}.

Comment: Actually, I am asking about the polynomial. Thank you for the binomial symbol. I have edited the question. Still, I am confused about what is the result of $p_j(x)$. Can you, please, provide me an example for, say, $D=3$ and $M=2$?

Comment: The 10 polynomials could be $1,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_1x_3,x_2^2,x_2x_3,x_3^2$ with $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Comment: So essentially the author is choosing a specific *basis* for the vector space of all polynomials in $M$ variables of degree less than or equal to $D$.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. It makes sense now. I would like to mark your comment as correct answer, but that is not possible. So thank you once more, you have helped me a lot.

Comment: @andybenji, M being the degree, D the number of variables

Comment: @andre Yes, oops